What effect would bent, stacked log periodic antennas have?
I am an amateur radio operator. I have an antenna called an “Arrow Antenna.” It has three elements along one axis for 2 meter wavelength (144 MHz) and 7 elements that are perpendicular for 70cm wavelength (440 MHz). It has a duplexer that runs a single cable to an HT (radio). I use this configuration to communicate through low earth orbit satellites (or receive from the ISS).
I have limited experience with log periodic antennas. I know that I could make a “serpentine” version where I take some 8 AWG wire and starting at the reflector portion of the antenna make it about 3.5 feet (106.68 cm) wide then move up to the next element serpentining back and forth making each element shorter. When I’m done the antenna should be around 3 foot long (around 95 cm). I know there are formulas that help you make sure each element is the correct length.
Imagine I made a second antenna the same way. Then on both antennas I bend the elements on each side of center the same direction so that the elements are 90 degrees from each other (folded them towards each other). I then attach the antennas so that they are opposite each other on a horizontal beam. In essence I am trying to “cross the elements” like they are on the Arrow Antenna I talked about.

Would this configuration work? I suspect I’m doing something significant to the design by making the elements of each antenna 90 degrees from each other instead of 180 degrees. Maybe this is a terrible idea?

Have I changed gain at all? My guess is the “flat” version is around 6dB of gain over iso.

Do I crosslink the out of phase elements like a non-serpentine log periodic antenna (one with just elements sticking out) would be configured? So the rear most reflector on one antenna is connected to the next element up on the other antenna, and then work my way up through the rest of the elements?

The reason I’m even trying to do this is to not need a duplexer. With that in mind do I connect the center of the antenna cable to one antenna and the shield of the antenna cable to the other antenna?



I confess I'm having difficulty understanding what geometry you're describing; a couple of diagrams would go a long way
